# Failing to load sqlalchemy-plugin in pyinstaller'ed exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller, alchemy

This line of code works perfectly fine while running as a file from spyder.

```
engine =  sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradata://uid:pwd@DBinstance?driver=Teradata')
```

However, after making an exe file using `pyinstaller`, I get the following error while running the exe:

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load
>   plugin:sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

This looks to be an exe-creation-issue in loading libraries. 
Has anyone encountered a similar issue and was able to resolve? Any pointers would be appreciated.